# How can we rename the whole Json file keys after transforming to Json in XSLT

Tags: json, xslt-3.0

I want to rename the keys whole Json file

```
{
  "squadName": "Super hero squad",
  "homeTown": "Metro City",
  "formed": 2016,
  "secretBase": "Super tower",
  "active": true,
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "age": 29,
      "secretIdentity": "Dan Jukes",
      "powers": ["Radiation resistance", "Turning tiny", "Radiation blast"]
    },
    {
      "name": "Madame Uppercut",
      "age": 39,
      "secretIdentity": "Jane Wilson",
      "powers": [
        "Million tonne punch",
        "Damage resistance",
        "Superhuman reflexes"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to rename the keys of whole Json file after transforming to Json in XSLT

Comment: How are you creating the JSON? Why not rename the keys *while* creating it? That said, what exactly do you want to rename? What's does the JSON shown look like *after* a successful renaming? (For that matter, what did the original XML look like, and what XSLT did you use to generate the JSON?)

Comment: It is not clear at which issue you struggle, what you have tried and how it failed.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds to me as if you just want to chain two transformations; assuming you want to deal with the JSON as XDM maps and arrays at some point I think you will need a recursive function processing a map.

Here is an example that, for simple input like maps of arrays that are of a single type (i.e. if we have an array containing a map all the array items are maps), transforms all keys to upper case letters (although that function is just a sample function passed to the higher-order function):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:transform-keys" as="map(*)">
    <xsl:param name="map" as="map(*)"/>
    <xsl:param name="key-transformer" as="function(xs:anyAtomicType) as xs:anyAtomicType"/>
    <xsl:sequence
      select="$map => map:for-each(function($k, $v) { 
                    map:entry($key-transformer($k), 
                              if ($v instance of map(*))
                              then mf:transform-keys($v, $key-transformer)
                              else if ($v instance of array(map(*)))
                              then array { $v?*!mf:transform-keys(., $key-transformer) }
                              else $v
                    )
                  }) => map:merge()"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of map(*)]">
    <xsl:sequence select="mf:transform-keys(., function($k) { upper-case($k) })"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This [transforms](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Amap%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%2Fmap%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Amf%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmf%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afunction%20name%3D%22mf%3Atransform-keys%22%20as%3D%22map%28*%29%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22map%22%20as%3D%22map%28*%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22key-transformer%22%20as%3D%22function%28xs%3AanyAtomicType%29%20as%20xs%3AanyAtomicType%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20select%3D%22%24map%20%3D%3E%20map%3Afor-each%28function%28%24k%2C%20%24v%29%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20map%3Aentry%28%24key-transformer%28%24k%29%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28%24v%20instance%20of%20map%28*%29%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20then%20mf%3Atransform-keys%28%24v%2C%20%24key-transformer%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%20if%20%28%24v%20instance%20of%20array%28map%28*%29%29%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20then%20array%20%7B%20%24v%3F*%21mf%3Atransform-keys%28.%2C%20%24key-transformer%29%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%20%24v%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29%20%3D%3E%20map%3Amerge%28%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afunction%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22json%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22.%5B.%20instance%20of%20map%28*%29%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%20select%3D%22mf%3Atransform-keys%28.%2C%20function%28%24k%29%20%7B%20upper-case%28%24k%29%20%7D%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22squadName%22%3A%20%22Super%20hero%20squad%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22homeTown%22%3A%20%22Metro%20City%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22formed%22%3A%202016%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22secretBase%22%3A%20%22Super%20tower%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22active%22%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22members%22%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Molecule%20Man%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22age%22%3A%2029%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22secretIdentity%22%3A%20%22Dan%20Jukes%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22powers%22%3A%20%5B%22Radiation%20resistance%22%2C%20%22Turning%20tiny%22%2C%20%22Radiation%20blast%22%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Madame%20Uppercut%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22age%22%3A%2039%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22secretIdentity%22%3A%20%22Jane%20Wilson%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22powers%22%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Million%20tonne%20punch%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Damage%20resistance%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Superhuman%20reflexes%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&input-type=JSON) your input

```
{
  "squadName": "Super hero squad",
  "homeTown": "Metro City",
  "formed": 2016,
  "secretBase": "Super tower",
  "active": true,
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "Molecule Man",
      "age": 29,
      "secretIdentity": "Dan Jukes",
      "powers": ["Radiation resistance", "Turning tiny", "Radiation blast"]
    },
    {
      "name": "Madame Uppercut",
      "age": 39,
      "secretIdentity": "Jane Wilson",
      "powers": [
        "Million tonne punch",
        "Damage resistance",
        "Superhuman reflexes"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

into e.g. (order of items in an XDM map is not defined)

```
{
   "HOMETOWN": "Metro City",
   "MEMBERS": [
      {
         "SECRETIDENTITY": "Dan Jukes",
         "NAME": "Molecule Man",
         "AGE": 29,
         "POWERS": [
            "Radiation resistance",
            "Turning tiny",
            "Radiation blast"
         ]
      },
      {
         "SECRETIDENTITY": "Jane Wilson",
         "NAME": "Madame Uppercut",
         "AGE": 39,
         "POWERS": [
            "Million tonne punch",
            "Damage resistance",
            "Superhuman reflexes"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "SECRETBASE": "Super tower",
   "SQUADNAME": "Super hero squad",
   "FORMED": 2016,
   "ACTIVE": true
}
```

For the initial transformation you also want to apply before that "global" key transformation you can use a variable and/or another mode or perhaps just some more XPath function calls e.g.

```
<xsl:sequence select=". => map:put('members',  array { ?members?* !  (map:put(., 'membersAge', ?age) => map:remove('age')) }) => mf:transform-keys(function($k) { upper-case($k) })"/>
```

Of course, the recursion, instead of using recursive functions, can also be done with XSLT templates (although it is a bit difficult in XSLT 3 as there is no XSLT instruction to construct arrays or array items):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:param name="key-upper-case" select="function($k) { upper-case($k) }"/>
  
  <xsl:mode name="transform-keys"/>
  
  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of map(*)]">
    <xsl:map>
      <xsl:variable name="map" select="."/>
      <xsl:for-each select="map:keys($map)">
        <xsl:map-entry key="$key-upper-case(.)">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$map(.)"/>
        </xsl:map-entry>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:map>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of array(*)]">
    <xsl:param name="key"/>
    <xsl:variable name="array-items" as="item()*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="?*"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$key">
        <xsl:map-entry key="$key-upper-case($key)" select="array { $array-items }"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:sequence select="array { $array-items }"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match=".[not(. instance of map(*)) and not(. instance of array(*))]">
    <xsl:param name="key"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$key">
        <xsl:map-entry key="$key-upper-case($key)" select="."/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:sequence select="."/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could then chain that stylesheet with `fn:transform`, for instance, to the result of a previous transformation step:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

<xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match=".[. instance of map(*)]">
  <xsl:sequence
    select="(. 
            => map:put('members',  array { ?members?* !  map:put(., 'membersAge', ?age) })
            => map:remove('age'))
            ! transform(map { 'stylesheet-location' : 'sheet2.xsl', 'initial-match-selection' : ., 'delivery-format': 'raw' })?output"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```